# log4j2 in Spring Boot slows down my application significantly

Tags: java, spring-boot, performance, logging, log4j2

I built a REST API with `Spring Boot` and I switched my logging framework to `log4j2` by adding an exclusion of the default logger in my `pom.xml`:

```
<exclusion>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
</exclusion>
```

As well as including `log4j2` instead:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I'm experiencing insane slowdowns of my REST API. I realized that `log4j2` is calling the `toString()` methods of my `data JPA` entities seemingly "out of nowhere" (e.g. I didn't specifically write log statements to log them out). I suppose this causes massive overhead (by potentially also fetching more entities from the database).

By reverting back to the default logger `Logback` the performance is "normal" again. `Logback` also does not call the `toString()` methods "out of nowhere". Why is `log4j2` so inefficient here and can this behavior of calling my `toString()` methods "out of nowhere" be turned off?

Comment: Are you able to override the `toString` method and add a break point to see why `toString` is called?

Comment: @samabcde: Yes, I overwrote it basically for every entity and when it's called, it's not from me code but from some framework code which I don't have any control over.

Comment: So can you see which method is calling `toString` when you stop at the breakpoint?

Comment: @samabcde: It's called by invoking certain repository interface methods, e.g. ones that I defined myself. Since the code is generated by Spring Data JPA, I don't see any explicit calls to `toString()` but they happen anyway.

Comment: Can you add some examples of logging statements? My guess is that you activated some very verbose logger in your config (Hibernate statements?).

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz: My log statements do not log out any entities so I'm not calling `toString()` implicitly either. Yes, I enabled Hibernate SQL logging via e.g. `logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG`, `logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE`, `spring.jpa.show-sql=true`

Comment: I would guess that Hibernate calls `toString()` on your entities. Can you add a stacktrace to the question?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz: The stack trace is just a regular repository method which my code is calling such as `findFirstByGameModeOrderBySeasonIdDesc(gameMode)` but "magically" `toString()` is being called inside of it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I wasn't able to figure out why `log4j2` is mysteriously calling my entity's `toString()` methods, severely degrading performance, I decided to use the default `Logback` logger and I ended up being quite happy with it, so I don't really need to use `log4j2` anymore. After all, `Logback` is also the default logger for `Spring Boot`. Sometimes it's better not to break a running setup.